# Feynman Chapter 13

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I was reading Feynman's lectures on Quantum Mechanics. In chapter 13 he derived the amplitude to find an electron in a 1-D lattice for a stationary state. This amplitude is a pure immaginary number for each atom of the lattice. Does this mean the probability is 100% for every amplitude?

Comment: There are purely imaginary numbers with a magnitude different from 1

Comment: Yes, but he gets an immaginary number with coefficient 1 (amplitude = e^(something))